# Drush fails "unable to copy" to drush-backups?

Tags: drush

When I run $ drush pm-update I receive an "Unable to copy" error.

> Unable to copy /mnt/hd0/vhosts/yourwebsite.com/drupal-7.36 to /home/ec2-user/drush-backups/opencall/20150422140414/drupal.               [error]
>   Unable to move /mnt/hd0/vhosts/yourwebsite.com/drupal-7.36 to /home/ec2-user/drush-backups/opencall/20150422140414/drupal.               [error]
>   Failed to backup project directory /mnt/hd0/vhosts/yourwebsite.com/drupal-7.36 to

Any thoughts? I'm sure it will run if I use sudo but that has other undesirable consequences.

Comment: Drush does run and complete successfully for another site I am running on the same server as another vhost. Permissions on both seem to be the same for both??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I've solved it.

Looks like someone previously ran Drush in the sudo environment and that had the effect of setting permissions to 6226 all over the place.

Updated manually and fixed permissions as I went.

Comment: Where and what did you update manually? I've just set ~/drush-backups to chmod 777 and the error is still happening

Comment: Check permissions of folders in your Drupal 'sites' directory and subdirectories. Mine were screwed up (set to 6226) everywhere Drush had touched when i stupidly ran is as root. Had to manually fix them all. 

It's tricky business so make sure you backup before playing with permissions.